# How can we concatenate variables and add leading zeros in R?

Tags: r, string-concatenation

Suppose I am interested in concatenating two variables. I start with a dataset like this:

```
#what I have
A <- rep(paste("125"),50)
B <- rep(paste("48593"),50)
C <- rep(paste("99"),50)
D <- rep(paste("1233"),50)

one <- append(A,C)
two <- append(B,D)

have <- data.frame(one,two); head(have)
  one   two
1 125 48593
2 125 48593
3 125 48593
4 125 48593
5 125 48593
6 125 48593
```

A straightforward paste command does the trick:

```
#half way there
half <- paste(one,two,sep="-");head(half)
[1] "125-48593" "125-48593" "125-48593" "125-48593" "125-48593" "125-48593"
```

But I actually want a dataset that looks like this:

```
#what I desire
E <- rep(paste("00125"),50)
F <- rep(paste("0048593"),50)
G <- rep(paste("00099"),50)
H <- rep(paste("0001233"),50)

three <- append(E,G)
four <- append(F,H)

desire <- data.frame(three,four); head(desire)
  three    four
1 00125 0048593
2 00125 0048593
3 00125 0048593
4 00125 0048593
5 00125 0048593
6 00125 0048593
```

So that the straightforward paste command produces this :

```
#but what I really want
there <-  paste(three,four,sep="-");head(there)
[1] "00125-0048593" "00125-0048593" "00125-0048593" "00125-0048593"
[5] "00125-0048593" "00125-0048593"
```

That is, I want the concatenation to have five digits for the first part and 7 digits for the second part with leading zeros applied when applicable.

Should I first transform the dataset to add the leading zeros and then do the paste command? Or can I do it all within the same line of code? I put a `data.table()` tag because I'm sure there is a very efficient solution there that I'm simply not aware of.

test solution provided by @joran:

```
one <- sprintf("%05s",one)
two <- sprintf("%07s",two)
have <- data.frame(one,two); head(have)
    one     two
00125 0048593
00125 0048593
00125 0048593
00125 0048593
00125 0048593
00125 0048593
desire <- data.frame(three,four); head(desire)
  three    four
00125 0048593
00125 0048593
00125 0048593
00125 0048593
00125 0048593
00125 0048593

identical(have$one,desire$three)
[1] TRUE
identical(have$two,desire$four)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%05d",125)
[1] "00125"
> sprintf("%07d",125)
[1] "0000125"
```

And if you are padding strings instead of integers, maybe:

```
sprintf("%07s","125")
[1] "0000125"
```

Comment: I didn't use `sprintf("%07s","125")` because on my system (Win R64) I get `[1] "    125"`

Comment: @SimonO101 That's unfortunate. `sprintf` is pretty useful!

Comment: thanks @joran! I was just writing code to convert to numeric first; works like a charm!

Comment: @joran I mean it does with numerics but with character I don't get leading zeros I get leading spaces!??

Comment: @SimonO101 Well, the docs _do_ say that it's just a wrapper for your system's sprintf C function. I supposed the Windows version is different...?

Comment: ah right, that would explain it, thanks! And +1 for the nice answer btw.

Comment: @SimonO101 see my edits for where I test the solution; works fine on Mac OSx and *NOT* Windows 7 for me

Comment: @hubert_farnsworth I don't doubt it at all, what I am saying, is that this command `sprintf("%07s","125")` gives me "   125" on my system. `R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03); Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit); [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252`

Comment: @SimonO101, Huh. I didn't catch that with Joran's answer here. It doesn't give me leading zeroes either...

Comment: ah. I also note at the bottom of the `?sprintf` page *The behaviour on inputs not documented here is ‘undefined’, which means it is allowed to differ by platform*

Comment: So it's just a `Windoze` vs. `*nix` thing. The important thing is Hubert has (a) numeric data and (b) access to a *nix environment so it's all good!

Comment: Weird little quirk; unfortunately the ``Windoze`` machine has the big server! But ``as.numeric()`` before ``sprintf("%07d",Var)`` is an easy work around

Answer (score 3):

Or use `paste0` and `paste`. `paste*` is vectorised so you can do:

```
half <- paste(paste0("00",one), paste0("00",two) , sep = "-");head(half)
#[1] "00125-0048593" "00125-0048593" "00125-0048593" "00125-0048593"
#[5] "00125-0048593" "00125-0048593"
```

But you have different string widths. An alternative (`sprintf` did not give the same results on my system) would be to paste with more zeros than you know you will need and then trim to the desired length:

```
one <-  paste0("0000000000000000",one)
two <-  paste0("0000000000000000",two)
fst <- sapply( one , function(x) substring( x , first = nchar(x)-4 , last = nchar(x) ) )
snd <- sapply( two , function(x) substring( x , first = nchar(x)-6 , last = nchar(x) ) )
half <- paste( fst , snd , sep = "-");head(half)
```

But I agree this is not a particularly good way of doing things. I'd use `sprintf` if I could get that output with character class data! (work with numeric class)

Comment: And if one of those numbers in the set were "25" and you wanted "00025"? I think `sprintf` is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: agreed; that's why I put the 99 and the 125 in the same column, etc. I tried this first and gave up -- sprintf is definitely what I was looking for , thanks!

Comment: @AnandaMahto @hubert_farnsworth I have updated!! `sprintf` did not give the same output on my system! I got leading spaces when dealing with data of `character` class.

Comment: +1 for going the extra mile, but I think that converting to numeric might be easier :)

Comment: @AnandaMahto lol. agreed. But now I want to know why `sprintf("%07s","125")` doesn't give me leading zeros.